# Obtener el valor de retorno de una función

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo una función `Prueba2()`, que debería *setear* el valor a una variable `'b'` dependiendo del valor que retorne `Prueba()`. Pero me toma como ***undefined*** `a b`, y solo se solucionarlo si paso los valores con una variable global ('c' en este caso). Hay alguna forma de hacer eso sin pasar los valores por la variable global? Este es mi código (PD: el WM únicamente retorna un `true`):

```
var c = false;
function prueba2() {
var b = false;
b = prueba();
d = c;
debugger;
}
function prueba() {
var a = false;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ABM/Cliente.aspx/PruebaWM',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function (msg) {
        debugger;
        a = msg.d;
        c = msg.d;
        return c;
    },
    error: function () {

    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hola tengo entendido que la funcion **success** siempre devuelve **undefined**. Y por lo tanto no se le asigna el dato correcto a la variable **b**. Lo que puedes hacer es pasar una funcion callback a la funcion **prueba** y recibir los datos devueltos. de esta manera.

```
var c = false;
    function prueba2() {
        var b = false;

        prueba(function(errorLanzado,datoDevuelto){
            if(errorLanzado){
                return;
            }
            a = datoDevuelto.d;
            c = datoDevuelto.d;

            b = datoDevuelto.d;
        });

        d = c;
        //debugger;
        console.log('El valor de b es: '+b);
    }

    function prueba(funCallBack) {
        var a = false;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ABM/Cliente.aspx/PruebaWM',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                funCallBack(null,msg);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

Espero el comentario de los usuarios.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Me funciono, ahora si me devuelve el valor. Lo de let no me lo solucionaba. Te hago otra consulta, si saco el async: false, no puedo obtener el valor porque se sigue ejecutando sin esperar el resultado del web method. Hay alguna forma de dejarlo que sea una funcion asincrona pero que obtenga le resultado igual?

Answer (score 4):

Eso te pasa porque `var` define el scope de las variables de una forma distinta a `let` y a `const`.

Tu problema se solucionar cambiando `var b = false;` por `let b = false;`

> > Te dejo un link a la documentación para que leas la teoria. Saludos

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/var
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/const

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. No me funciono utilizando let b = false; Sigue siendo indefinida. Se declara bien el valor al prinicipio, pero una vez que trato de asignarle el valor que devuelvue prueba() pasa a indefinido

Answer (score -1):

```
var c = false;
    function prueba2() {
        var b = false;

        prueba(function(errorLanzado,datoDevuelto){
            if(errorLanzado){
                return;
            }
            a = datoDevuelto.d;
            c = datoDevuelto.d;

            b = datoDevuelto.d;
        });

        d = c;
        //debugger;
        console.log('El valor de b es: '+b);
    }

    function prueba(funCallBack) {
        var a = false;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ABM/Cliente.aspx/PruebaWM',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                funCallBack(null,msg);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [answer], una explicación no vendría mal. Saludos